# C# XML LINQ Query to LIST<>

Tags: c#, xml, linq, list

I'm trying to turn an XML document into a List<> with a predefined Class

My xml dataset TestData.xml

```
<Objects>
    <Object ID="1">
        <ItemOne>"Hickory"</ItemOne>
        <ItemTwo>"Dickory"</ItemTwo>
        <ItemThree>"Dock"</ItemThree>
    </Object>

    <Object ID="2">
        <ItemOne>"The"</ItemOne>
        <ItemTwo>"Mouse"</ItemTwo>
        <ItemThree>"Went"</ItemThree>
    </Object>
</Objects>
```

The Main program

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        XElement TestData = XElement.Load("TestData.xml");

       List<Test> myTest = new List<Test>(from d in TestData.Descendants("Objects")
                                     select new Test(
                                         d.Element("ItemOne").Value.ToString(),
                                         d.Element("ItemTwo").Value.ToString(),
                                         d.Element("ItemThree").Value.ToString()));

        myTest.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", i.itemOne, i.itemTwo, i.itemThree));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }


}
```

The class I'm trying to form the data to

```
class Test
{
    public string itemOne { get; set; }
    public string itemTwo { get; set; }
    public string itemThree { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to get out

```
Hickory Dickory Dock
The Mouse went
```

but I end up getting nothing.  It looks like the LINQ Query finds the data but never assigns it to the `List<Test>` myTest, the value shows as null in the debugger.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I want to convert the XML to `List<Test>` so I can randomly rearrange through the objects.  I was going to just use int[] array and sort by "ID" but I don't know the actual length of the array and want to assign it on the fly so I am forced to do a `list<>`.  I am open to other suggestions of accomplishing this.

Comment: Don't you mean `List<Test> myTest`?

Comment: @ZevSpitz I think it's `List<Quiz>` because the constructor in the LINQ query is also for class `Quiz`. The list constructor is maybe wrong though.

Comment: `d.Element("ItemOne").Value.ToString()` - `Value` is itself a `string`, so calling `ToString` is redundant. Also, it's more robust to cast the `XElement` to `string` -- `(string)d.Element("ItemOne")` -- rather then retrieve the `Value`, because if there is no such element `.Element` returns `null`, and `.Value` will cause a `NullReferenceException`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387049.aspx).

Comment: sorry the "Quiz" was a typo, but thanks for the other advice it actually solved a different problem I was having and looks cleaner too.

Comment: I edited it to fix the typo Quiz. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without having it tested, I think you should write `TestData.Descendants("Object")` instead of `TestData.Descendants("Objects")`. The parameter for `Descendants` must match the name of the nodes you want to select.

Answer (score 2):

You are already at the root that is `Objects`

Do this

```
from d in TestData.Descendants("Object")
                               --------
```